# c# await in for loop

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a list of items that need to be updated if information is missing. However, I'm making a call to Google Location services to do that. I'm wondering how I can append the necessary Lat & Long information asynchronously if possible

my code

```
public static void PullInfo()
{
   foreach (var item in SAPItems)
   {
        if(item.MDM_Latitude == null || item.MDM_Longitude == null)
        {
             var point = GetMapPoint(item.AddressLine1 + " " + item.FiveDigitZip);
             item.MDM_Latitude = point.Result.Latitude.ToString();
             item.MDM_Longitude = point.Result.Longitude.ToString();
        }                    
    }

    foreach(var item in SAPItems)
         Console.WriteLine(item.MDM_Latitude + " " + item.MDM_Longitude);
}

private static async Task<MapPoint> GetMapPoint(string add)
{
     var task = Task.Run(() => LocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(add));
     return await task;
}
```

Comment: @Rup Just set the numbers in that specific item object. I updated the question.

Comment: Why are you using `.Result` when you await your `GetMapPoint` function? After the await, you already have the data, just await there, not inside `GetMapPoint`.

Comment: Try changing the List to a ConcurrentBag and the foreach to a Parallel.ForEach

Comment: why can't you just say `var point = await GetMapPoint(item.AddressLine1 + " " + item.FiveDigitZip);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get multiple map points asynchronously with multiple tasks (notice that it requires to convert `PullInfo()` to async-await):

```
public static async Task PullInfo()
{
    // Create tasks to update items with latitude and longitude
    var tasks
        = SAPItems.Where(item => item.Latitude == null || item.Longitude == null)
            .Select(item =>
                GetMapPoint(item.AddressLine1 + " " + item.FiveDigitZip)
                    .ContinueWith(pointTask => {
                        item.MDM_Latitude = pointTask.Result.Latitude.ToString();
                        item.MDM_Longitude = pointTask.Result.Longitude.ToString();
                    }));

    // Non-blocking await for tasks completion
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // Iterate to append Lat and Long
    foreach(var item in SAPItems)
        Console.WriteLine(item.MDM_Latitude + " " + item.MDM_Longitude);
}

private static Task<MapPoint> GetMapPoint(string add)
{
     return Task.Run(() => LocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(add));
}
```

If `PullInfo()` cannot be converted to async-await, you can force the thread to wait for the results, but it will block the current thread:

```
public static void PullInfo()
{
    // Create tasks to update items with latitude and longitude
    var tasks
        = SAPItems.Where(item => item.Latitude == null || item.Longitude == null)
            .Select(item =>
                GetMapPoint(item.AddressLine1 + " " + item.FiveDigitZip)
                    .ContinueWith(pointTask => {
                        item.MDM_Latitude = pointTask.Result.Latitude.ToString();
                        item.MDM_Longitude = pointTask.Result.Longitude.ToString();
                    }));

    // Wait for tasks completion (it will block the current thread)
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    // Iterate to append Lat and Long
    foreach(var item in SAPItems)
        Console.WriteLine(item.MDM_Latitude + " " + item.MDM_Longitude);
}

private static Task<MapPoint> GetMapPoint(string add)
{
     return Task.Run(() => LocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(add));
}
```

Running example of this last code sample: https://ideone.com/0uXGlG

Comment: I've run this method, but my missing latitudes and longitudes are still not being assigned. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3434042 The first or the second one? Do you want to update Latitude/Longitude  or MDM_Latitude/MDM_Longitude?

Comment: tasks.ToArray() will cause the enumerable to be iterated. No need for the last foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to await the call to getting the data (notice how the `await` got moved from `GetMapPoint`):

```
public static async Task PullInfo()
{
   foreach (var item in SAPItems)
   {
        if(item.Latitude == null || item.Longitude == null)
        {
             var point = await GetMapPoint(item.AddressLine1 + " " + item.FiveDigitZip);

             item.MDM_Latitude = point.Latitude.ToString();
             item.MDM_Longitude = point.Longitude.ToString();
        }                    
    }

    foreach(var item in SAPItems)
         Console.WriteLine(item.MDM_Latitude + " " + item.MDM_Longitude);
}

private static Task<MapPoint> GetMapPoint(string add)
{
     var task = Task.Run(() => LocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(add));
     return task;
}
```

You're not modifying your `SAPItems` collection, just each individual item. Once you have the response, you can just update the then-current item in the loop.

Comment: Putting `await` in the middle of the loop will compile to a really messed up state machine, and will break the intended logic. The answer Guillermo gave is the way to do it.

Comment: @Nik Why do you think it'll break the logic?

Comment: My apologies, thinking about this further (but I haven't tested), it shouldn't break the logic, but the state machine does compile to something way more complicated than it needs to be. Use ILSpy (or whatever you use) to see how your proposed method compiles compared to the accepted answer. In particular, look at the compiler generated `MoveNext()` method. If one was to implement this before C#5, I doubt someone would be tempted to create such logic. To me, you should nor write code that compiles to something you would never code without the syntactic sugar...but that's just me :-)

Comment: @Nik meh, I don't much care about the compiler's problems :) I agree that Guillermo's answer is more efficient because it has more parallelism - I just fixed the original code as is - he reworked it to a greater degree. I'm sitting in conference calls all day today :D