# Call of async method in foreach loop run once

Tags: c#, async-await, maui

```
  [ICommand]
    async Task GetStatesAsync(string partname)
    {
        try
        { 
            var states = await cityService.GetStates(partname);   

            StatesList.Clear();


            foreach (var state in states)
            {
                var citylist = await cityService.GetCities(state.Id); 
                state.CityList = citylist;
                state.CityCount = citylist.Count;
                StatesList.Add(state);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

I mean this  part

```
var citylist = await cityService.GetCities(state.Id);
```

of the code runs once, i.e. for the first time and all states get cities of the first record.
What is wrong whith this?

Comment: from a url I mean an online webApi

Comment: What does `GetCities` return? IEnumerable/IQueryable? You might use the `ToList(..)` to persist it.

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing obvious wrong with the example code. What happens if you run the method a second time? How does the WebAPI code look? Does the `cityService` do anything more than creating the URI and parsing the result?

Comment: Yes, GetCities return a List<City>.

Comment: The only thing I can see that, Í run the code in development(emulator), probobly because of netowork connection, cannot run tow async methods in the same call.

Comment: just try with for loop instead of foreach

Comment: You can try to use the `List<Task>()` and the `Task.WhenAll()` to do that. Such as [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082617/c-sharp-await-in-for-loop) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431494/how-to-use-await-in-a-loop). @Shaahin